# Levi-Civita connection for a metric in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

> Let $g$ be a metric in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined as $\partial_{x}, \partial_{y}, \partial_{z}$ are orthogonal everywhere, and $g(\partial_{y},\partial_{y})=1, g(\partial_{z},\partial_{z})=f(x), g(\partial_{x},\partial_{x})=f(x)$ for $f$ being a positive function. Compute $\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{j}$ for all $i,j$ being $x,y$ or $z$ and $R^{\nabla}$ (the Riemannian curvature tensor). Moreover, show that for $M=\{x=c\}$, the restricted metric is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

For the first question, this is just computing the Levi-Civita connection for the metric $g$. This can be computed with the Cristoffel symbols for the metric. However, I'm not sure on how to compute them as we are not given a metric of the form $u dx^{2}+v dy^{2}+t dz^{2}$. What would be a way of writing the metric in this form? Or would it just be easier to compute it using an index-free argument? I'm not sure on how to proceed since we haven't covered much of this in class.

For the second question, since $R^{\nabla}$ is tensorial in all slots, it suffices to compute $R^{\nabla}(\partial_{i},\partial_{j})\partial_{k}$ for all $i,j,k$ being $x,y,z$. Is this correct? If so, would it just be $\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\partial_{k}-\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{k}$ since the Lie bracket $[\partial_{i},\partial_{j}]$ vanishes? For the final question, I think this would be equivalent to showing that $g(\partial_{i},\partial_{j})=\langle \partial_{i}, \partial_{j} \rangle_{Euc}$. How would I go about this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question in a way that will change the correctness of solutions you have received once you have received them. It is clear that the same idea as in my answer will work for the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you work in the global coordinates $(x,y,z)$ this is just a computation together with a thorough understanding of the definitions.

First, the usual proof of the existence of the Levi-Civita connection gives the coordinate formula for the Christoffel symbols
\begin{align} \label{a}\tag{1}
\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac12 g^{kl}(\partial_i g_{jl} + \partial_j g_{il} - \partial_l g_{ij})
\end{align}
where I have adopted the usual summation convention, identified $g$ with its matrix in these coordinates and written $g^{kl} = (g^{-1})_{kl}$.

The information you're given about $g$ says precisely that in the obvious coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $g$ has matrix representation
$$g_{(x,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix}
f(x)&0&0& \\0&1&0& \\0&0&f(x)&
\end{bmatrix}.$$
From here, finding $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ is just a computation using (\ref{a}). You should get the non-zero Christoffel symbols to be
\begin{align}
\Gamma_{ij}^k(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} -\frac{\partial_xf(x)}{f(x)}  \quad \text{ if } i = j \in \{1,3\} \text{ and } k = 1, \\ \\
\frac{\partial_xf(x)}{f(x)} \quad \text{ if } \{i,j\} = \{1,3\} \text{ and } k = 3.
\end{cases}
\end{align} 
Computing the curvature tensor is again just a computation in the global coordinates using the identity
$$R = R_{ijk}^{\,\,\,\,\,l} dx^i \otimes dx^j \otimes dx^k \otimes \partial_l$$
where $R_{ijk}^{\,\,\,\,\,l}$ satisfies $R_{ijk}^{\,\,\,\,\,l} \partial_l = R(\partial_i,\partial_j) \partial_k$. As you noticed, this computation is made easier by the fact that the Lie brackets $[\partial_i, \partial_j]$ all vanish and hence is straightforward (if lengthy) now you know the Christoffel symbols.

We are left to see that $M = \{x=c\}$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$. First, let's see what the induced metric on $M$ is. It is clear that $(c,y,z) \mapsto (y,z)$ is a global coordinate chart on $M$ and that $\operatorname{Id}:M \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is an immersion. Let $\tilde{g} = \text{Id}^* g$ be the induced metric on $M$. It is not too hard to check that $\tilde{g}$ has matrix
$$\tilde{g}_{(c,y,z)} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&f(c) \end{bmatrix}$$ with respect to our global coordinates on $M$.

Notice here that $g$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\text{Euc}}$ act on different spaces so one can only write $g(\partial_i, \partial_j) = \langle \partial_i, \partial_j \rangle_{\text{Euc}}$ up to some identification between the spaces - i.e. if we are thinking of $\partial_k$ on the RHS as really meaning $d\Phi (\partial_k)$ for some diffeomorphism $\Phi: M \to \mathbb{R}^2$. I assume that your idea was to take $\Phi(c,y,z) = (y,z)$ but it is clear from the matrix form of $\tilde{g}$ that this won't work.

Instead, it is natural to define the map $\Phi: M \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\Phi(c,y,z) = (y, \sqrt{f(c)} z)$. It is immediate that $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism so we want to check that $\tilde{g} = \Phi^* \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\text{Euc}}$. For this, it is enough to check that $\Phi^* \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\text{Euc}}$ has the right matrix representation.

This is another computation. We have, for example,
\begin{align}
\Phi^* \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\text{Euc}}(\partial_z |_p, \partial_z |_p) = \langle d\Phi_p (\partial_z |_p), d\Phi_p (\partial_z |_p) \rangle_{\text{Euc}}
\end{align}
Now, it isn't too hard to see that for $F \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $p = (c,y,z)$ we have
$$d\Phi_p (\partial_z |_p)(F) = \partial_z |_p (F \circ \Phi) =  \sqrt{f(c)} \partial_z|_{\Phi(p)} F.$$
Therefore $d\Phi_p (\partial_z|_p) = \sqrt{f(c)}\partial_z|_{\Phi_p}$ and so 
$$\Phi^* \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\text{Euc}}(\partial_z |_p, \partial_z |_p) = f(c) = \tilde{g}(\partial_z |_p, \partial_z |_p).$$
The other entries in the matrix follow similarly.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I mixed up $g(\partial_{x},\partial_{x})$ and $g(\partial_{y},\partial_{y})$ (they should be $1$ and $f(x)$, respectively). For part 1 and 2 it shouldn't change anything in the argument, but would it make it any different for part 3? (I assume that the matrix for the restriction would be $f(c),f(c)$ in the diagonal). I'm still getting through the argument used in your part 3. Also, for part 2, I'm not sure on what do you mean. I learned that $R^{\nabla}(X,Y)Z=\nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}Z-\nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X}Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ is the curvature tensor...

Comment: ... wouldn't computing it for $\partial_{i,j,k}$ be sufficient to give us $R$? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In part $3$ you would indeed now get $\tilde{g} = f(c) \operatorname{Id}_{2\times 2}$ and so accordingly you will instead want to take $\Phi(c,y,z) = \sqrt{f(c)} (y,z)$ and then the same argument will work.

Comment: That is the definition of the curvature tensor I am using. Notice that $R^{\nabla}(X,Y)Z$ is a vector field and so we can think of $R^\nabla$ as a multilinear map from $\Gamma(TM)^3 \times C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. as a $(3,1)$-tensor). As a $(3,1)$-tensor, it has the representation I gave in local coordinates, which here are global. It would also be enough to compute $R^{\nabla}(\partial_{i},\partial_{j})\partial_{k}$ by multilinearity which amounts really to doing the same thing and is simple once you know the Christoffel symbols.